# Trigger useEffect from functional Component with global variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

my question is if it is possible to trigger useEffect with a variable from outside the component.

In my case i have this main component that has the useEffect responsible to update info every time the variable "refresh" changes.

```
function Main() {

const [data, setData] = useState([])
const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false)

useEffect(async () => {
    await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/api/data/`)
        .then(res => {
            setData(res.data); 
        })
}, [refresh]);
```

And then i have a function that i can invoke inside the component or child that triggers the useEffect, updating the data.

```
    const refreshData = () => setRefresh(!refresh);
```

So far so good, it works as i wanted but now i needed to export this function to use in a component not related to this one, but i know that you cannot export a function declared inside a component.

So my idea was to create this same function outside the component, like so:

```
    let refreshOutside = false;

    export const refreshMainFromOutside = () => {
        refreshOutside = !refreshOutside;
    }
```

So now i can add the variable "refreshOutside" to the useEffect, like so:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/api/data/`)
        .then(res => {
            setData(res.data); 
        })
}, [refresh, refreshOutside]);
```

But if i import it in other component and invoke the method it does not trigger the useEffect, i am kinda new to react but i think its because the component is not re-rendering.

Is there any solution that might work on my case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you simply define a separate function to fetch the data and use it both inside useEffect() and as a callback to pass to the component that should trigger the refresh?

Comment: what is the point of doing this? you can just call a function which calls your api

Comment: I could, but then i could not update the state inside the main component

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put your hooks inside another file for example `useComponent.js` and export your `refreshData` as const inside it, then use that hook inside any component you wish:

```js
const useComponent = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false)

    useEffect(async () => {
        await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/api/data/`)
            .then(res => {
                setData(res.data); 
            })
    }, [refresh, refreshOutside]);

    const refreshData = () => setRefresh(!refresh);

    export { refreshData }
}

export default useComponent
```

import the hook inside any component then destructure functions and use them:

```js
import useComponent from '../hooks/useComponent'

const MyComponent = () => {

   const { refreshData } = useComponent()

   return <button onClick={refreshData}>Click to refresh!</button>

}

export default MyComponent
```

Comment: React does not let me export refreshData inside a component,
"'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level"

Comment: `useComponent` is not a component, it's a custom hook. It allows you to reuse the functions. If you want to have a global variable you can use context hooks inside this hook.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you can simply define a separate function to fetch the data (and memoize it with the `useCallback()` hook), then you can use that function wherever you want in your Main component and in any Child component to whom you pass it as prop.

Maybe an example would make it easier to understand:

```js
const Main = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  
  const updateData = React.useCallback((startIndex) => {
    /*
    axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/api/data/`)
      .then(result => {
          setData(result.data); 
      })
    */
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('fetching data...');
        setData(result.data.slice(startIndex, startIndex + 5));
        console.log('... data updated');
      });
  }, [setData]);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    updateData(0); // fetch & update `data` when the Main component mounts
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Main</h1>
      {
        data.length > 0
          ? <ul>{data.map(item => <li>{item.title}</li>)}</ul>
          : <p>'There are no data'</p>
      }
      <button
        onClick={() => updateData(5)} // fetch & update `data` on request, on button click
      >Refresh from Main</button>
      <Child handleClick={updateData} />
    </div>
  )
}

const Child = ({handleClick}) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Child</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => handleClick(10)} // fetch & update `data` on request, on button click
      >Refresh from Child</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

P.S. in the above example I used a parameter (`startIndex`) for the `updateData()` function just to keep the `data` state short and make it change when different buttons are clicked (because the API I used always returns the same data). In a real case use you are unlikely to do something like that because you can implement pagination on API side (if needed) and your API response is supposed to change over time (or you would not need a way to refresh your data).
Anyway, the point is that what I did inside the `updateData()` function body is mostly irrelevant; the main take away of the snippet is supposed to be how you can handle a function that needs to be called inside hooks, inside the main component and by child components.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, i think i understand what you did there, but in my case, maybe not the best practice, is that the component that i want to give access to the refresh is not related to the main component(coz of various reasons of the project).

Yet in your solution you need to have a relationship with main component? am i right?

Comment: Yes, in the example I provided `Child` must be a descendant of `Main`. If `data` is the only "piece" of state that needs to be accessed by not-related components, maybe you can try to use a handle the problem relying on [`useContext()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) (you might want to have a look at this article: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usecontext-hook). If there are other "pieces" of state that needs to be shared among non-related components, instead, you might want to consider using a state container like Redux or similar.

Comment: i appreciate your answer, gonna take a look at those. In reality the only thing that i want to share is the function that changes the value of refresh.

const refreshData = () => setRefresh(!refresh);

Since its declared inside the component i can't just export it. I must figure out a way to do this, but thanks anyways